# Windows Azure Web Sites Java integration

Tags: windows, azure

I am new to Windows Azure. My Java based web/mobile application needs Tomcat and mysql. Is it possible to run this in Azure Web Sites. I have not seen anything related to Java on this except mysql service. I am thinking of to trgger a VM for everything, but still I cannot link my sources, ofcourse I need to invest time to link them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure websites.

To create a new website with Tomcat 7 (`+new`->`web site`->`From gallery`->`Apache Tomcat 7`). This area is still changing. Yesterday that was the way to do it.

Today there is a JAVA section in your Azure web site configuration where you can select java version and container.

As you point out in the question, you have to create the mysql database and do the linking manually.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Azure virtual machine, then deploy your war file onto the tomcat instance running in Azure.

Microsoft even have a [Tomcat azure tutorial here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/tutorials/tomcat-on-a-virtual-machine/).

Another solution which @DavidMakogon rightly pointed out would be to use the Azure Cloud Services option which also has Eclipse integration, these act as managed VMs, but with admin access.

Comment: Is there a way to link my sources to my vm then?

Comment: No, when you say "link your sources", you'd need to wrap up your code into a war.  If you want to "link your sources" then Amazon do an addon for AWS with Eclipse that auto-deploys your code, but in practice for production I'd say this is never a good idea and builds should always be a process rather than on the fly to production.

Comment: To clarify: Azure Virtual Machines aren't the only vehicle for Java on Azure; you can also run Java just fine in a stateless web/worker role Cloud Service (essentially managed VMs, but with admin access). This is a common scenario, and it's supported out-of-the-box through Eclipse on Windows.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks. Atleast is there a way to avoid ssh-ing to update the source. Especially if I load balance, I need to write a script then to update my source in several machines. Is there any out of the box way to update the source in my vm?

Comment: @DavidMakogon I'll delete my answer in a few minutes as I don't think it gives it justice given what you've mentioned, I wasn't aware Azure had Eclipse integration like AWS.

Comment: @david99world I'd leave the answer. Maybe just edit to point out there are both Virtual Machines & Cloud Services as options. Good to know about both.

Comment: FYI there's a new answer posted by @steenhulthin - as of today, we now support Java in Web Sites.

Answer (score 0):

On April 3rd 2014, at Build, Microsoft announced the support for Java Web Applications on Microsoft Azure Websites - Check it out http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-get-started/